# Android localization strings from xml

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I have `xml` folder in my `res` folder with file structured like this:

```
    <questions>
        <question
            number="1"
            text="my string" 
            numberTwo="1" />
         ...
    </questions/
```

So is that possible not to hardcode strings here and use @string/... resources because I really need localization here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have

`text="mystring"` in your xml file

and `<string name"mystring">lalala</string>` in your strings.xml (possibly localized in other files such as in a folder values-de.xml)

Then in your code you can do:

```
int stringId = getResources().getIdentifier("mystring", "string");
String string = getString(stringId); // that will be "lalala"
```

The other way is to have your xml file entirely localized in the folder xml-de but this incurs some text duplication.

Answer (score 0):

In string.xml ->lalala in your strings.xml 
->folder values-de.xml
Then in your code you can do in Activity:

```
String AppName=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```

And in Fragmetn

```
String AppName=getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
```